# What is the right way to enumerate using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Code:

```
 var result = db.rows.Take(30).ToList().Select(a => AMethod(a));
```

db.rows.Take(30) is Linq-To-SQL

I am using ToList() to enumerate the results, so the rest of the query isn't translated to SQL

Which is the fastest way of doing that? ToArray()?

Comment: An interesting fact that I came across is that for correlated queries caused by using a group defined through a group join in your projection causes Linq to SQL to add another sub-query to retrieve the count for that group. I'm assuming that this means in these cases the size of the collection will be known before the items are retrieved and thus an exact sized array could be created directly which would save on processing and memory resources while materializing the results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx):

```
var result = db.rows
               .Take(30)
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Select(a => AMethod(a));
```

Comment: For those that don't click into the link, all AsEnumerable does is return its argument typed as IEnumerable<T>. This will preserve deferred execution and eliminate the need for the intermediate data structure created by ToList() or ToArray().

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enumerable.AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) if you don't want to execute the database query immidiatly because because `AsEnumerable()` will still deffer the database query execution until you start enumerating the LINQ to Object query.

If you are sure that you will require the data and/or want to immidiatly execute the database query, use [Enumerable.ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) or [Enumerable.ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx). The performance difference should be not to big.

I assume the rows are read into a variable sized container at first in both call, because the number of rows is not yet known. So I tend to say that `ToList()` could be a bit faster, because the rows could be directly read into the list while `ToArray()` probably reads the rows into a kind of list at first and then copies to an array after all rows have been transfered.