# Entity Framework appears to be needlessly joining the same table twice

Tags: linq, entity-framework

**Update** This may already be fixed: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/486

...

A fairly straightforward LINQ statement against my entities is resulting in unnecessarily complex SQL.  More on that later, here's the setup:

**Tables**

*Publication*

- PublicationId (pk)
- TopicId (fk to a Topic table)
- ReceiptCount (denormalized for query performance)
- DateInserted

*Receipt*

- ReceiptId (pk)
- PublicationId (fk to the table above)
- DateInserted

**LINQ**

```
var query = from r in context.Receipts.Include("Publication")
            where r.DateInserted < lagDate
            && r.ReceiptId > request.AfterReceiptId
            && r.Publication.TopicId == topicEntity.TopicId
            && r.Publication.ReceiptCount > 1
            select r;
```

**SQL**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (25) 
[Project1].[ReceiptId] AS [ReceiptId], 
[Project1].[PublicationId] AS [PublicationId], 
[Project1].[DateInserted] AS [DateInserted], 
[Project1].[DateReceived] AS [DateReceived], 
[Project1].[PublicationId1] AS [PublicationId1], 
[Project1].[PayloadId] AS [PayloadId], 
[Project1].[TopicId] AS [TopicId], 
[Project1].[BrokerType] AS [BrokerType], 
[Project1].[DateInserted1] AS [DateInserted1], 
[Project1].[DateProcessed] AS [DateProcessed], 
[Project1].[DateUpdated] AS [DateUpdated], 
[Project1].[PublicationGuid] AS [PublicationGuid], 
[Project1].[ReceiptCount] AS [ReceiptCount]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ReceiptId] AS [ReceiptId], 
    [Extent1].[PublicationId] AS [PublicationId], 
    [Extent1].[DateInserted] AS [DateInserted], 
    [Extent1].[DateReceived] AS [DateReceived], 
    [Extent3].[PublicationId] AS [PublicationId1], 
    [Extent3].[PayloadId] AS [PayloadId], 
    [Extent3].[TopicId] AS [TopicId], 
    [Extent3].[BrokerType] AS [BrokerType], 
    [Extent3].[DateInserted] AS [DateInserted1], 
    [Extent3].[DateProcessed] AS [DateProcessed], 
    [Extent3].[DateUpdated] AS [DateUpdated], 
    [Extent3].[PublicationGuid] AS [PublicationGuid], 
    [Extent3].[ReceiptCount] AS [ReceiptCount]
    FROM   [dbo].[Receipt] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Publication] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PublicationId] = [Extent2].[PublicationId]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Publication] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[PublicationId] = [Extent3].[PublicationId]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[ReceiptCount] > 1) AND ([Extent1].[DateInserted] < @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[ReceiptId] > @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent2].[TopicId] = @p__linq__2)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[ReceiptId] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 datetime,@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__2 int',@p__linq__0='2012-09-05 19:39:21:510',@p__linq__1=4458824,@p__linq__2=90
```

**Problem**

Publication gets joined twice:

1. LEFT OUTER JOIN because of `.Include("Publication")`
2. INNER JOIN because of the `where`.

If I remove [Extent2] from the SQL entirely, and change the WHERE bits to use [Extent3], I get the same results back.  Since I'm not using Lazy Loading on my entities, I have to `.Include("Publication")`... is there any solution for this?

I was using EF4, but grabbed EF5 from NuGet to see if it was perhaps fixed, but it produces the same result (although I have no idea how to tell if my EDMX is really using EF5).

Comment: I think you are exactly right the where and include are both doing joins and its not simplifying to the left join. You should post this as an improvement to the EF Codeplex project. However I imagine it will be pretty low priority as I imagine SQL will be pretty efficient with this

Comment: "Even" NHibernate has issues like this. Consider it a peculiarity of automated query generation. The database engine will probably optimize it out. Nice observation though.

Comment: @GertArnold It actually is causing performance issues.  SQL Profiler is reporting Duration to be 700-900 ms, where as if I remove it, I get 0-6 ms.

Comment: Boy! Bad news. Looks like it need improvement after all.

Comment: @Langdon which clause are you removing?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I removed the `INNER JOIN` from the SQL.  I cannot seem to make any adjustment to the LINQ that fixes the query AND gives me all the data I need.  FYI- The Publication and Receipt tables have 800k+ rows each (didn't see any performance issues until we had a few hundred thousand rows).

Comment: I think @saml has the right idea (ie select both the things you care about into an autonomous type, i have a suspicion that this will also populate the nav property on receipt but im not 100% sure), however i think all you need to do is remove the include and change your select line to `select new { Receipt = r, Publication = r.Publication }` then you can add a `.ToArray().Select(r=> r.Receipt)` to the end of the whole thing to enumerate the set and give you the actual receipts collection

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I think you're right about that (and commented on his answer before I saw your comment here), but `.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Receipt)` should be sufficient, there's no need to create an array.

Comment: @hvd actually you want to use a .tolist or .toarray or similar as they will enumerate the set (ie execute the query and pull it down from the db) .AsEnumerable is still a deferred execution so it hasnt executed the query when you call this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099675/what-is-the-right-way-to-enumerate-using-linq

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I didn't realise you wanted immediate execution, but if you do, I think `.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Receipt).ToList()` would still be better, the list created there is the list you actually want.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I tried just the select new { } bit without the Include, but the same issue occurred.  I think `select new { Publication = r.Publication }` was the same as doing .Include and forced the unnecessary join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is however, a work-around.  It may not be the most elegant solution, but it does exactly what you want; it generates only one join.

Change:

```
var query = from r in context.Receipts.Include("Publication")    
            where r.DateInserted < lagDate 
            && r.ReceiptId > request.AfterReceiptId 
            && r.Publication.TopicId == topicEntity.TopicId 
            && r.Publication.ReceiptCount > 1 
            select r;
```

To be:

```
var query = from r in context.Receipts
            join pub in context.Publication on r.PublicationId equals pub.PublicationId
            where r.DateInserted < lagDate 
            && r.ReceiptId > request.AfterReceiptId 
            && pub.TopicId == topicEntity.TopicId 
            && pub.ReceiptCount > 1 
            select new {
                Receipt = r,
                Publication = pub
            };
```

Note that we have removed the Include AND we are no longer using r.Publication.?? in the where clause.  Instead we are using pub.??

Now when you loop through query, you will see that r.Publication is not null:

```
foreach ( var item in query)
{
    //see that item.Publication is not null
    if(item.Receipt != null && item.Receipt.Publication != null)
    {
        //do work based on a valid Publication
    }
    else
    {
        //do work based on no linked Publication
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this would be interpreted as a `INNER JOIN` and not as a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @edze It's supposed to be an inner join. `a INNER JOIN b AS b1 LEFT JOIN b AS b2` (the double join that prompted this question) will never return null rows for `b2`, because all the `a`s that lack `b` rows have been filtered out by the first join already.

Comment: That said, this same idea should be doable with `r.Publication` too: removing the `Include` in the original query and adding `select new { Receipt = r, Publication = r.Publication }` should work without manually joining on `PublicationId`

Comment: @hvd, In fact I tried that first, but again the r.Publication.?? in the where clause seemed to be executed against a different Join than that of the select.

Comment: @saml Actually testing myself now, the query in the question doesn't generate the double join for me. It does if I add `.Take(25)` based on the generated SQL in the question, but the SQL I get is still different. I'm not sure what the original query *really* looks like.

Comment: @saml Brilliant, thanks!  I attempted using the join syntax instead of include but foolishly didn't consider changing the select or adjusting my where clause.

Comment: @hvd That's interesting about `.Take()` being necessary... As you can see in the generate SQL, I was doing `.Take()` (and an `.OrderBy()` before that) but didn't think it was relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior can be avoided by using temporary variables (eg, `let` pub = r.Publication).

```
var query = from r in context.Receipts
            let pub = r.Publication // using a temp variable
            where r.DateInserted < lagDate
            && r.ReceiptId > request.AfterReceiptId
            && pub.TopicId == topicEntity.TopicId
            && pub.ReceiptCount > 1
            select new { r, pub };
```

Comment: If 'Publication' had a child what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I will optimize on previous person's answer by changing the code as below, which removes the need of join so you don't have to know what columns you need to join and also don't have to change LINQ when join criteria gets changed. This should have been unnecessary but MS is not focused on fixing their sql code generation right now.

```
    var query = from pub in context.Publications
                from r in pub.Reciepts
                where r.DateInserted < lagDate 
                && r.ReceiptId > request.AfterReceiptId 
                && pub.TopicId == topicEntity.TopicId 
                && pub.ReceiptCount > 1 
                select new {
                       Receipt = r,
                       Publication = pub
                };
```